# Why is "www." considered unsafe in this HTTPS URL?

Tags: tls

I was doing some cross-origin requests to  Soundcloud's [oEmbed](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#oembed) and I noticed some strange behaviour.
When doing a request from my localhost, which is on a regular HTTP connection, everything worked fine. However, when the code got pushed on our HTTPS test server, I got the following error from my browser:

> [blocked] The page at
>   'https://example.com' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but ran insecure content from
>   https://www.soundcloud.com/oembed?url=https://soundcloud.com/gwatsky/pumped-up-kicks-remix&format=js&callback=JSON_CALLBACK: this content
>   should also be loaded over HTTPS.

The request URL is `//www.soundcloud.com/oembed?url=https://soundcloud.com/gwatsky/pumped-up-kicks-remix&format=js&callback=JSON_CALLBACK`. Note the "**www.**".

I tried specifying the protocol to HTTPS and removing/specifying the protocol in the `url` parameter, but I kept getting the error.

In the end I removed the `www.` from the URL and everything started working fine.

**tl;dr** Why is having `www.` in this HTTPS URL considered a security risk?

Comment: As David pointed out, SoundCloud is redirecting requests at `https://www.soundcloud.com` to `http://soundcloud.com`. Since https is dropped, your browser will complain of insecure content.

Comment: It seems that the issue has been resolved by soundcloud by now.

Comment: Web security strongly relies on hostnames. And a hostname `www.soundcloud.com` is not the same as `soundcloud.com` -- browsers and SSL certs are very strict about this. (And there are right and wrong ways to configure servers to handle these discrepancies. Sometimes mistakes, like a faulty 301 redirect, cause errors like this.)

Comment: Soundcloud was notified about this so I guess they just fixed it.

Comment: It should be noted that the Chrome error message is rather bad too, because it complains about loading insecure content from what looks like perfectly valid secure URL without mentioning the bad redirect anywhere.

Comment: You know nothing.

Comment: @Yogu When I visit `https://www.soundcloud.com/oembed` it still redirects me to the non-https site.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I think you are making a huge assumption with your question:

> Why does Chrome consider the "www." in an HTTPS url as a security risk?

as this is simply not the case.

What is happening is that SoundCloud is forcing users from `www.soundcloud.com` to `soundcloud.com` with a 301 redirect. The problem is that they are redirecting all traffic to `http://soundcloud.com` regardless of the originating protocol.

This is simply a configuration issue with the Soundcloud website and has nothing to do with browser or web security standards. There is no inherent risk with the www subdomain to a website.

The solution as you have already figured out is to remove the www in order to avoid the redirect. You might want to make the site's administrators aware of the issue if you are so inclined.

Comment: Alright I'll rephrase the question.

Answer (score 15):

Your browser is showing this warning because Sound Cloud apparently has incorrectly configured redirect for the following URL:

> https://www.soundcloud.com/oembed

redirects to:

> http://soundcloud.com/oembed

Notice the normal "http". This is why the browser is raising a red flag when embedded inside another https-based website/page. Whereas,

> https://soundcloud.com/oembed

is not getting redirected and thus remains on the secure side of http.

Answer (score 0):

The observation and behavior is correct, but the conclusion is wrong. The SSL certificate is issued in two ways

1. To the site. In your case soundcloud.com . As per the naming convention, soundcloud.com and www.soundcloud.com are two different names. Hence https site accessed with www.soundcloud.com, it denied saying the certificate is not issued to www.soundcloud.com . This does not mean there is issue or it is unsafe. The data is still going over SSL layer and provides same protection when accessed over soundcloud.com.
2. In corporate sites, the certificate is issued to wildcard domains. But the wildcard certificates are very expensive and hence, most customers avoid going with wild card. In wild card case, the certificate is issued to *.domain. In your case if the certificate is issued as *.soundcloud.com then www.soundcloud.com or soundcloud.com all will work. even w3.soundcloud.com  anything.soundcloud.com will also work.

I appreciate you brought a very good topic for discussion, but one need to understand the entire SSL certificate, domain , naming behavior in this case.

Many times, improper configuration of root certificate chain in server leads to error as well.

Comment: It is true example.com and www.example.com are different for cert name matching. But the error message here was clearly mixed content, not cert name mismatch. And the cert for this site (from GlobalSign DV SHA2 G2) has SubjectAltNames specifying BOTH `soundcloud.com` and `*.soundcloud.com`. Further, `*.foo` matches `www.foo` and 'w3.foo` and 'anything.foo` but not plain `foo`; see RFC 2818 and http://serverfault.com/questions/447222/ssl-certificates-for-domain-without-www .